# Custom Swift UIGestureRecognizer does not call assigned action

Tags: ios, swift, action, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIViewController with a custom UIGestureRecognizer added to one of its views. The problem is that i get all the touch printlines from my DialGestureRecognizer but the handleDial action is never called. (iOS 8 / Xcode 6.1.1) What did i do wrong? Any help appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet var dialView:UIView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let _dialView = dialView? {
        let recognizer = DialGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:"handleDial:")
        _dialView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }

    func handleDial(recognizer:DialGestureRecognizer) {
        println("handleDial")
    }
}
```

The custom (stripped down) UIGestureRecognizer looks like this

```
class DialGestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer {        
    func touchesBegan(touches:NSSet!, withEvent event:UIEvent!)  {
        println("touchesBegan")
    }

    func touchesMoved(touches:NSSet!, withEvent event:UIEvent!) {
        println("touchesMoved")
    }

    func touchesEnded(touches:NSSet!, withEvent event:UIEvent!) {
        println("touchesEnded")
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger the selector from inside the gesture recogniser.
To trigger the selector, you have to modify the state property of the UIGestureRecognizer. This property is readonly.

For modifying that you have to add a BridgingHeader as follows.

You need to have or create a `-Bridging-Header.h` file to import Objective C headers such as the one you want.

If you don't already have a bridge header file in your app, the easiest way to get one is to add an objc class to your project, and xcode will ask if you want one, then creates the file and ties it into the settings for you. You can then delete the objc class.

Add the next line to the `Bridging Header` file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>
```

Then you can modify the `self.state` property to get the events fired.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches:NSSet!, withEvent event:UIEvent!)  {
    println("touchesBegan")
    self.state = UIGestureRecognizerState.Began
}
```

For more information read
http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Comment: This answer put me on the right track. I now added `import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass` together with the `self.state` assignments to my code and everything just works